Replacement motherboard for Lenovo Thinkstation E30
I have a Lenovo Thinkstation E30. It's Serial number is S4HZBN7. As I have found out it contains the motherboard called "fru einstein 1.0 motherboard", its part number is 03T8244. This link contains an image of it https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/175507920799
I want to buy a new motherboard RAM and CPU into it. The aim is to get more up-to-date performance, and to gain Windows 11 compatibility. I am not a fan of throwing everything away, so I would like to keep the graphics card, the hard drives and the housing including the power supply.
Can you tell me which motherboards are fitting into this case? I need something compatible with the power supply and with the peripherals. Which form factor do I need, what should I take care of?

Looks like mATX. While I applaud your desire to avoid throwing stuff away, I do want to point out that the case, power supply, and graphics card (in this particular case) are rather old and not very performant, and the latter two may need to be replaced (or should not be reused) anyways depending on your use case. You mentioned improved performance; what workloads specifically are you doing that you'd like to be faster?

Thanks for your response. I have now such a graphic card inside, since I wanted to use a 4k display: MSI GeForce GTX 1050 TI 4GT LP 4GB Nvidia GDDR5 1x HDMI, 1x DP, 1x DL-DVI-D, 2 Slot Low Proflie, Afterburner OC, Nvidia G-Sync, Grafikkarte.

So graphic card is good enough for me. As for performance I would like to have something in higher middle section. Not the most expensive CPU, but also not something I would need to replace in a few years. This setup is actually 10 years old apart from the graphic card, and it was good enough for me. I would keep the new motherboard, CPU and RAM surely for a similar time period.

Can you clarify what you're actually using your machine for? Giving an appropriate CPU recommendation requires knowing what you're using said CPU for.
